# How IDE know that variable?

Tags: python

```
def y(v0,t):
 g=9.81
 return v0*t - 0.5*g*t**2   
v0 = 5
time = 0.6
print(y(v0,time))
```

in this code how does the computer understand the time variable even though the t variable is used in the code?

I was thinking that a t variable should be added instead of time

Comment: I hope this article will answer your question [declare and invoke parameters in python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-function-examples-how-to-declare-and-invoke-with-parameters-2/)

Comment: This is what almost all computer languages do when you pass values into functions: There is some sort of assignment so that the value outside the function is assigned to the parameter name used inside the function. This is also useful when there is no named variable outside the function, eg a call like: `y(v0, time/2)`

Comment: That depends on your IDE. From a Python perspective it's all about "pass by value"